# how can i read line by line from a variable in bash

Tags: bash, shell-script

How to read variables line after line

```
 PROMOTEBUILDS=3.1.161,1.0.132
    echo cat ${PROMOTEBUILDS} | while read -r line; do
    egrep $line /home/rahul-optit/packages
    done
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you're using bash you should use an [array](https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/bash/manual/bash.html#Arrays) instead of a variable:

```
promotebuilds=( 3.1.161 1.0.132 )
for i in "${promotebuilds[@]}"; do
  egrep "$i" /home/rahul-optit/packages
done
```

Answer (score 3):

@Jesse_b's answer is the way to do it.

If you however have no influence on the input, you can use `IFS=,` and `read` to split the string and make it an array.

```
printf '%s' "$PROMOTEBUILDS" | IFS=, read -a promotebuilds
for i in "${promotebuilds[@]}"; do
  egrep "$i" /home/rahul-optit/packages
done
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I do not understand the question. For one thing, your variable appears to have only one line.

All this time I've been reading lines from a variable the same way you would from a regular file except I enclose it in quotation marks and use '<<<' instead of '<' to feed it to the while loop.

```
VARIABLE=$(cat somefilewithmultiplelines)
while read i ; do echo "$i" ; done <<< "$VARIABLE"
```